# Difficulty loading multiple LATEX's symbols in a mathematical website

Tags: html, mathml

how are you doing?

For some time now, I've been writing some texts about Olympiad mathematics on a wiki. You can find this wiki at the following address: `https://olimpedia.fandom.com/pt-br/wiki/Wiki_Olimp%C3%A9dia...`

There, you can find several pages with mathematical content. However, recently, some pages that contain many symbols in LaTeX have been having trouble loading them. Instead of displaying the symbols, error messages like the following appear: "Failed to check grammar (MathML with SVG or PNG fallback (recommended for modern browsers and accessibility tools)): Invalid response ("Math extension cannot connect to Restbase.") from the server "https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/":): {}."

Until some time ago, these pages were able to load LaTeX symbols, but nowadays, it seems that they no longer have the capability. Here's an example if you want to see it in practice: `https://olimpedia.fandom.com/pt-br/wiki/Desigualdade_das_M%C3%A9dias`

This page is hosted on the site `https://www.fandom.com/`. I would love for these pages to be able to load all the mathematical symbols. Is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it relates to non-TeX based systems for typesetting maths on a website which, although inspired by TeX, do not use TeX itself and therefore expertise in TeX won't be helpful in finding an answer to thus question. It is therefore better to ask it elsewhere.

Comment: Apart from the fact that this is not really a TeX problem, if I follow [the link you cite](https://olimpedia.fandom.com/pt-br/wiki/Desigualdade_das_M%C3%A9dias), I cannot reproduce the problem you describe. At least, the mathematical formulas on this page seem to render fine for me. If what you describe is a problem with your browser or with the site, there is probably nothing we can help you with anyways and you should get in touch with the people who host this site.

Comment: sorry about that. do you guys know some place to ask this question?